# How to customize blocking behavior of BlockingQueue

Tags: java, queue

I want to create a blocking queue which blocks producer on the basis of customized rules instead of number of items in the queue.

For example:

Producer produces some files and puts into a queue. Consumer transfers them to a specific location after some analysis.

For above scenario, I want producer waiting to produce new files if the size of total files in the queue reaches some threshold value. Queue can accept any number of files if the total size don't cross threshold value.

Comment: have you found any solutions till now?

Comment: It's a very old question. And I didn't use blocking queues in any real application yet. So I didn't try very hard to search for a solution after that.

Comment: I have the same need and I couldn't find anything ready-made. I'll probably just copy-paste LinkedBlockingQueue's code from Java (written by Doug Lea) and modify the existing logic of checking "capacity" and "count" to actually invoke a custom check or something. Can't come up with anything easier/shorter.

Answer (score 4):

I would probably subclass a `BlockingQueue` such as the [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) and add a simple `CountDownLatch` which is initialized to the threshold value and enables the various `take`/`remove` methods when reaching 0.

Comment: I was expecting some inbuilt mecanism provided by java to customizing blocking behaviour by overriding some method or something else that is can't guess. Because rules can be changed as per the need.

Comment: I can see how such class could be useful. I'm not entirely sure I understand your requirements though. If `take` should block until tere is 10 elements in the queue, should I be able to `take` ten elements then, or should I have to wait for 9 elements to become 10 again?

Comment: For the prsented scenario, `take` will not wait untill queue is empty. But `put` will wait if the total size of files (**not number of files**) crossed thrashhold value. Suppose the thrashhold value is 5mb then `put` will wait if queue has 1000 files of 5 KB or 100 files of 50 KB (in rough figure).

Comment: I would suggest using composition rather then inheritance to modify behavior of blocking queue.

Comment: @Ivan, You're right. That probably makes more sense. You would probably have to implement all methods of the BlockingQueue anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to implement this locking mechanism yourself. You could use wait/notify or ReentrantLock/Condition, a long variable holding the combined length and a LinkedList holding the files.

Comment: This is the last option in my solution queue as @aioobe suggested. :)