# Concurrent blocking queue with isFull predicate

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, queue

I have one IO-thread (producer) which read files into RAM and multiple workers (consumers) hat make CPU-heavy processing. So there will be something like `ArrayBlockingQueue<FileProcessingRequest>` t, where *FileProcessingRequest* looks like:

```
public class FileProcessingRequest {
    private String path;
    private byte[] content;
    private int size; // in bytes
}
```

*Is there any concurrent blocking queue implementation which will block IO-thread (producer) based on summary of `FileProcessingRequest`'s `size`s?* Let's say producer will be blocked after loading 2GB of data.

*Maybe it's possible to customize one of the existent solutions instead of writing own solution?*

Comment: Subclass `LinkedBlockingQueue`?

Comment: @xTrollxDudex yet `BlockingQueue` is in the `java.util.concurrent` package...

Comment: @Kayaman yet ConcurrentBlockingQueue is not...

Comment: @xTrollxDudex there is no `ConcurrentBlockingQueue` in the JDK. But there's nothing funny about it. `BlockingQueues` are both concurrent (i.e. thread-safe) and blocking. They don't exclude each other in any way.

Comment: @Kayaman how to subclass LinkedBlockingQueue if all members are final?

Comment: The same problem, still no solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256324/how-to-customize-blocking-behavior-of-blockingqueue

Comment: `LinkedBlockingQueue` isn't `final`, although the linked question does suggest composition instead of inheritance. I know you're looking for a ready solution so you don't need to make an effort, but I'm sorry, I just can't be bothered to write one up right now.

Comment: You can use BlockingQueue + Semaphore.